# how to get the mac address of the client router through which the client logged in to my website in asp.net webforms?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to check if the client logged in to my website is in the company location or not so I want to get the mac address of the client router to check if the router is in the company or no

Comment: Even if this is doable programmatically, it would be too easy to fake it.

Comment: the mac address is unique so where is the problem ? 
Can you explain , please ?